# XSLT - check node is exist or not using function

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <meta-data>
        <paper-name>ABC</paper-name>
        <paper-type>fi</paper-type>
    </meta-data>

    <section>
        <figure>fig1</figure>
        <figure>fig2</figure>
    </section>
</doc>
```

My requirement is, if `<paper-type>` node is available in  `<meta-data>` change `<figure>` nodes to `<image>` node.

So, output should look like,

```
<doc>
    <meta-data>
        <paper-name>ABC</paper-name>
        <paper-type>fi</paper-type>
    </meta-data>

    <section>
        <image>fig1</image>
        <image>fig2</image>
    </section>
</doc>
```

I have written following xsl to do this task,

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="abc:check-paper-type" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:sequence select="root()//meta-data/paper-type"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="figure[abc:check-paper-type()]">
        <image>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </image>
    </xsl:template>
```

to check `<paper-type>` node is available inside `<meta-data>` I have written a function here named 'check-paper-type'. but is does not work as expected.

Any suggestion how can I organize my function to check, `<paper-type>` is available or not?

Note that, I need to change lots of node by checking `<paper-type>` node exist or not. So, It'll be important to check `<paper-type>` exist or not by using a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your attempt cannot work is this:

> Within the body of a stylesheet function, the focus is initially
>   undefined; this means that any attempt to reference the context item,
>   context position, or context size is a non-recoverable dynamic error.
>   [XPDY0002]

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#stylesheet-functions

You could do simply:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure[../../meta-data/paper-type]">
    <image>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </image>
</xsl:template>
```

Given your input, this will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
   <meta-data>
      <paper-name>ABC</paper-name>
      <paper-type>fi</paper-type>
   </meta-data>
   <section>
      <image>fig1</image>
      <image>fig2</image>
   </section>
</doc>
```

---

Alternatively, if you need to refer to the existence of the  node repeatedly, you can define it as a *variable*, instead of a *function*:

```
<xsl:variable name="check-paper-type" select="exists(/doc/meta-data/paper-type)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure[$check-paper-type]">
    <image>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </image>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: this is a sample code and I need to change lots of node names by checking <paper-type> node is exist or not. So, it will be more effective if I can use a function to check that <paper-type> is available or not. My apologies for lack of details in original question.